# Fechar sidenav quando width for menor que 700

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Tenho um sidenav do material design angular que eu preciso que quando o width for menor que 700, abrir a tela com o nav fechado, e quando for maior que 700 a tela pode abrir com o nav aberto.

Tentei algo como:

```
 @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;

  mobHeight = screen.height
  mobWidth = screen.width;

  fechaNav(){
    this.sidenav.close();
  }

  constructor() {
    if(this.mobWidth < 700){
      this.sidenav.close();
    }
  }
```

Também tentei no ngOnInit porém a tela continua abrindo com o nav aberto.

Essa função  this.sidenav.close() está correta, eu uso ela para fechar o sidenav quando o usuário clica em algum item, mas por algum motivo não estou conseguindo executar ela em conjunto com o constructor ou ngoninit.

Comment: Tenta com o ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

Pra pegar a width da tela faz assim:

```
innerWidth: number;

ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if(this.innerWidth < 700){
        this.sidenav.close();
   }
}
```

Pra manter atualizado no resize

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```